# Output wont show (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I  have 1 input. And it has to print out 2 outputs 1 with -1 to the output and the other with -2. But the output doesn't show anything. can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

**Code:**

```
// Meters en Centimeters value
function updateTotal() {
  const list = document.getElementsByClassName("AutosubmitCalculator");
  const values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    values.push(parseFloat(list[i].value));
  }
  let total = values.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + currentValue;
  });
  document.getElementById("schermentotaal").value = total - 2;
  document.getElementById("schermentotaal2").value = total - 1;
}
```

**HTML Input:**

```
<div class="InputField InputMeters">
    <input type="tel" name="iFenceMeters" id="FenceMeters" class="AutosubmitCalculator" data-minimum-length="1" tabindex="1" placeholder="00" maxlength="3" value="">
    <div class="FormExclamation Tipped Hidden" id="FormCalculatorExclamationFence">0</div>
</div>
```

**HTML Output:**

```
<div class="SummaryRow">
  <strong>Schermen</strong>
  <input name="schermentotaal" type="text" id="schermentotaal" value=""></input>
</div>

<div class="SummaryRow">
  <strong>Palen en onderplaten</strong>
  <input name="schermentotaal2" type="text" id="schermentotaal2" value=""></input>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different.

Comment: 1) `i++` and `++i` are not the same. 2) You have no element with ID `total`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen as the increment in `for` loops, it doesn't matter whether one writes `i++` or `++i`. They only differ in their return value, and here no return value is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling your `updateTotal` anywhere. I suggest you run this function on the `oninput` event on your input field. This will make it so that whenever you enter a number it will run the function `updateTotal`.

You also have some additional errors, such as you are trying to get the element with the id `total` but don't have an element with this `id` in your HTML.

```
document.getElementById("total").value
```

I've changed this to be `schermentotaal2` which is a valid `id` in your HTML:

```
document.getElementById("schermentotaal2").value
```

See working example below:

```js
function updateTotal() {
  const list = document.getElementsByClassName("AutosubmitCalculator");
  const values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    values.push(parseFloat(list[i].value));
  }
  let total = values.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + currentValue;
  });
  document.getElementById("schermentotaal").value = (total - 2) || '';
  document.getElementById("schermentotaal2").value = (total - 1) || '';
}
```

```html
<div class="InputField InputMeters">
  <input type="tel" name="iFenceMeters" id="FenceMeters" class="AutosubmitCalculator" data-minimum-length="1" tabindex="1" placeholder="00" maxlength="3" value="" oninput="updateTotal()" />
  <div class="FormExclamation Tipped Hidden" id="FormCalculatorExclamationFence">0</div>
</div>


<div class="SummaryRow">
  <strong>Schermen</strong>
  <input name="schermentotaal" type="text" id="schermentotaal" value="" />
</div>

<div class="SummaryRow">
  <strong>Palen en onderplaten</strong>
  <input name="schermentotaal2" type="text" id="schermentotaal2" value="" />
</div>
```

Also, if you only have one input you may want to reconsider using a class to get the input value for this as you don't require a loop to get the value from one input field.

Comment: I added this to my code. And now it shows nothing and when i give input it give me "0" in both outputs.

Comment: @J.Coderino when you run the code snippet above, it gives you the correct answer right? I made a small edit to the answer, does it do what you expect now?

Comment: Yes. So could it maybe be that the input area is in another div etc?

Comment: So are you usuing the exact code I provided you with ^ ?

Comment: Yes I am. I copied the code and pasted it. So I dont know what could be the problem. look this is what i get: https://gyazo.com/9e11e282da020f86d59bca974cc3ba20

Comment: are you getting any errors in your browser console (right click then click "inspect element" then click the "console" tab)

Comment: No nothing. Empty. I copy pasted your code again. I removed some of my scripts. And now i get totally nothing.

Comment: Hm, its hard for me to tell what's going wrong. Could you possibly give me a link to the server you're running your website on (if it's not running locally) or post all your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: So, in my example, we only have one input box. But in your example, you have two input boxes (`m`, `cm`). Do you want the input to only effect the output when you enter a number into one of these boxes (eg: If I enter a value into `m` then it shows an output, but if I enter a number into `cm` it does nothing)

Comment: I have 2 inputs. But only M has to work the other doesnt really matter. But when i give input to M it needs to show those inputs that got to work in your fiddle. But yhea.. it just doesnt want to show that. It only shows whats behind the "||" you put in the script. And if i remove those i get "NaN".

Comment: Ok, so you need to add the class `calcTotal` to the `m` input. Then change `document.getElementsByClassName("AutosubmitCalculator");` to `document.getElementsByClassName("calcTotal");` Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/h6kc421y/1/

Comment: Yheaa, thanks very much man. Appreciate it. I can finally go and work on the other functions :)

Comment: @J.Coderino Hye, I saw your previous question and was about to answer it until it got deleted, I coded [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9yjakoL2/) up and think it might help.

Comment: Owh sorry @NickParsons I thought no one was reacting anymore and it died out. So i just deleted it. I'll try it out and repost my question. And mark yours as answered if you want.